# String Operation using Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I am trying to convert `FOO BAR BAZ` to `"GPCSC[", "N@@"` using linq.

I came this close:

```
var res2 = new String("FOO BAR BAZ ".ToList().Select((x, i) => x = (i % 2 == 0 ? ++x : --x )).ToArray());
```

which outputs

> GNPC@SC@[

I need to split this string into two parts so that my output will be

```
`"GPCSC[", "N@@"`
```

I couldn't sort it out yet.

Any solution advice on this?

**PS: I am looking for simple solution, not bunch of lines of codes**

Fiddle Link : https://dotnetfiddle.net/ml8bOC

Comment: That is some crazy task! Are you an alien? :-)

Comment: I am sure that It has very elegant way.

Comment: I can't seem to make sense of it to be honest. why would you want to do this?

Comment: Just say `(x, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? x + 1 : x - 1` instead, that is less confusing. ___EDIT:___ I mean `(x, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? (char)(x + 1) : (char)(x - 1)` :-)

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise with your spec? You said "Foo Bar Baz" but your code has "FOO BAR BAZ", very different things if we're talking ascii/int conversions/manipulations etc. The strings you have/want/say you get etc are different lengths, quotes, backticks, can't tell what is output and what is markdown. Please improve

Comment: That line doens't output the string GNPC@SC@[ but GNP C@S C@[ where the withe spaces are the hex 1F

Comment: @Aomine this is for challenging myself. I am trying to find neat solution for this. But I also would like to see optimized / good answers and compare my solution to make it better.

Comment: @Steve I fixed the input sorry

Comment: Similar to the answer by dontpanic, you can do `"FOO BAR BAZ ".Select((x, i) => new { Val = i % 2 == 0 ? x + 1 : x - 1, Idx = i, }).GroupBy(t => t.Idx % 3 == 1).Select(t => String.Concat(t.Select(z => (char)z.Val)));` which will give you an `IEnumerable<string>` with the two strings in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use `GroupBy`:

```
string str = "GNPC@SC@[";

var groups = str.Select((v, i) => new { Group = i % 3, Ch = v })
                .GroupBy(item => item.Group == 1)
                .Select(group => string.Join("", group.Select(item => item.Ch)))
                .ToList();

// groups: ["GPCSC[", "N@@"]
```

Comment: Instead of `string.Join("", expr)`, you can say `string.Concat(expr)`.